# Theano partial derivative over element in symbolic vector

Tags: python, theano, derivative

I recently hit some performance bottlenecks with symbolic matrix derivatives in Sympy (specifically, the single line of code evaluating symbolic matrices via substitution using lambdas was taking ~90% of the program's runtime), so I decided to give Theano a go.

Its previous application was evaluating the partial derivatives over the hyperparameters of a Gaussian process, where using a (1, k) dimension matrix of Sympy symbols (MatrixSymbol) worked nicely in terms of iterating over this list and differentiating the matrix on each item.

However, this doesn't carry over into Theano, and the documentation doesn't seem to detail how to do this. Indexing a symbolic vector in Theano returns the Subtensor type, which is invalid for calculating the gradient on.

Below is a simple (but entirely algorithmically incorrect - stripped down to the functionality I'm trying to obtain) version of what I'm attempting to do.

EDIT: I have modified the code sample to include the data as a tensor to be passed into the function as suggested below, and included an alternate attempt at instead using a list of separate scalar tensors as I cannot index the values of a symbolic Theano vector, though also to no avail.

```
import theano
import numpy as np

# Sample data
data = np.array(10*np.random.rand(5, 3), dtype='int64')

# Not including data as tensor, incorrect/invalid indexing of symbolic vector
l_scales_sym = theano.tensor.dvector('l_scales')
x = theano.tensor.dmatrix('x')
f = x/l_scales_sym
f_eval = theano.function([x, l_scales_sym], f)

df_dl = theano.gradient.jacobian(f.flatten(), l_scales_sym[0])
df_dl_eval = theano.function([x, l_scales_sym], df_dl)
```

The second last line of the code snippet is where I am trying to get a partial derivative over one of the elements in the list of 'length scale' variables, but this sort of indexing is inapplicable to the symbolic vectors.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

When using theano, all variables should be defined as theano tensors (or shared variables); otherwise, the variable does not become part of the computational graph. In `f = data/l_scales_sym` the variable `data` is a numpy array. Try to also define it as a a tensor, it should work.

Comment: Thanks @Mehdi. I'm probably still missing large chunks of knowledge on how Theano works (working on that), but would this mean every time calculations are made, I will need to substitute my dataset back in? I don't have a grasp on how Theano stores and works with its data, so perhaps the overhead of needing to do this is far outweighed by the overall performance boost compared to using Sympy matrices.

Comment: The general process is often as the following: define variables (all the symbolic variables you want to use should be theano tensors, even when you use a scalar.) Next, you define your function as just you did using all math operations and theano functions such as `grad`. Next, use `theano.function([input list], output)' to compile your defined function. Then it becomes like a python standard function that you can call it with numpy array inputs. May also be good too see: [tutorial](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/gradients.html)

Comment: My main hurdle that doesn't seem to show up in any examples in the docs or in fact anything I've been able to find across various forums/etc. online is doing partial derivatives over every dimension of an original matrix of data - I've reflected some of the changes you suggested and a second attempt of doing this in the code snippet above.

Comment: Two issues: 1. The line `l_symbols = [theano.tensor.dvector('l' + str(i)) for i in range(data.shape[1])]` is a python list and not a matrix (i.e., a theano tensor). 2. In `theano.function([x] + l_symbols, df_dl0)` you should pass a list of inputs. The statement `[x] + l_symbols` should not be correct. But, I think for your problem you'd better use `shared` variables to make life easier. Have a look at this (http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/examples.html#using-shared-variables)

Comment: Thanks. Based on the basic examples they have though, I can't seem to get any closer to actually being able to have a tensor/symbolic type variable, and perform partial derivatives over each element of them - whereas this is almost trivial to in terms of logic in Sympy. If you could provide a basic example of this in your original post that would be great/I'll mark it as the accepted response.

Comment: Ok.. I see it now. The problem is due to `l_scales_sym[0]`. The sub-tensor operator is not differentiable, which causes the error. For example, say `x` is defined as a vector. Then while `T.grad(x[0], x)` is OK, `T.grad(x[0], x[0])` is NOT.

Comment: Yep - I realised that by differentiating over the whole vector, the resulting evaluated expression contains the partial derivatives over each variable but combined, requiring the programmer to unpack them to get the respective partial derivatives. Once I've fixed up a couple things I'll add this as the response later.